# Configure IdP Post Login Flow per-client

Tags: authentication, keycloak, multi-factor-authentication

I am using Keycloak 11.x and need to ensure users complete a second factor after they login with an external identity provider. The problem is, only some clients should be forced to utilize a second factor, not all clients.

Some of our client flows allow authenticating as a user with a set of standard roles, while other client flows are designed to allow authenticating with additional roles. I only want to force a second factor for these more sensitive clients.

In the provider settings, the `Post Login Flow` option seems to apply to all flows. Similarly for the `First Login Flow`

Is there any way to make the `Post Login Flow` a setting on the client (or the authentication flow) instead of a global setting on the provider?

Comment: Did you try to configure an IdP per client?

Comment: These are IdPs shown on the login screen, so unfortunately we can't configure copies and expect the user to select the right copy. Hiding them is also not an option, the goal is to let the user select and use the idp for their first factor

Comment: When you mention clients you are referring to client from a keycloak side right?

Comment: Correct, I am referring to the entries listed in the Clients portion of the admin console

Comment: hi @Hamy. I'm having the same problem as you describe. Did you found out any solution for this? Thanks for the help

Comment: @JoãoRebelo nothing yet. As far as I can tell KC simply does not support setting different post-broker flows depending on the frontend client used